# Can't connect to local database xampp

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, xamarin

I am trying to connect to my local database for my Xamarin app. But i am getting the error: `Unable to connect to anny of the specified MySQL hosts`. The database name password and user are all good.

Here is the code i am using:

```
private void LoginKnop_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("datasource=127.0.0.1;port=3306;username=root;password=JariR0800;database=test;");
    try
    {
        if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            con.Open();
            loginLog.Text = "Database geconnect";
        }
    }
    catch(MySqlException ex)
    {
        loginLog.Text = ex.ToString();
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();
    }
}
}
```

Thanks for your time!

Comment: you have an extra `}` at the end unless you forgot to post the `namespace {` anyway.. why don't you put the connection string into the .Config file also make sure you can connect to the Sql database via `IP Address`

Comment: use the actual IP address of your server, not loopback